# procedure or function '' expects parameter '' which was not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

please how to solve this problem. Message Error is:

> procedure or function 'ROHAN_GetPKList' expects parameter '@char_id' which was not supplied

I have SP

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ROHAN_GetPKList]
    @char_id    int
as      
set nocount on      
select top 100 k.pk_char_id,  c.[name], k.pk_char_type, k.pk_second, k.isKill, k.PKRecall, k.RecallRecharge, k.mode_type
    from TKill k, TCharacter c  
    where k.pk_char_id = c.[id] 
        and k.char_id = @char_id
        and c.[user_id] > 0
    order by k.[date]   

return @@error
```

and this is the table 'TKill'

```
    [char_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pk_char_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pk_char_type] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pk_second] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isKill] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [PKRecall] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [RecallRecharge] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [mode_type] [int] NOT NULL
```

and this is the table 'TCharacter'

```
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ctype_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cface_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [chair_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [mode] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [create_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [flag] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [cstyle_type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [cstyle_index] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [world_id] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [reward_time] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isSelling] [int] NULL,
    [pvppoint] [int] NULL,
    [pvppointoa] [int] NULL,
```

Comment: Show us the code that calls the proc. Common causes (using the ADO.NET API as an example) are 1) `CommandType.StoredProceedure` was not specified, 2) the parameter with that name was not added to the parameters collection, 3) the parameter value is null (rather than DBNull.Value).

Comment: sorry the application is packaged, I can not see the source code, but the error message appears ,, but I can edit the database

Comment: This looks to be an application issue so you need to contact the author. Not much you can do unilaterally on the server side.

Comment: ok thanks for respon

Answer (score 0):

Your error would appear to be when the procedure is *called*, not when it is being defined.  But I would suggest writing the code as:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[ROHAN_GetPKList] (
    @char_id    int  -- something called "char_id" with a type of "int" is strange
) as 
begin     
    set nocount on;  

    select top 100 k.pk_char_id, c.[name], k.pk_char_type, k.pk_second, k.isKill, k.PKRecall, k.RecallRecharge, k.mode_type
    from TKill k join
         TCharacter c  
         on k.pk_char_id = c.id
    where k.char_id = @char_id and c.user_id > 0
    order by k.[date]; 
    return @@error;
end;  -- ROHAN_GetPKList
```

Note the use of `BEGIN`/`END` and proper `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: `BEGIN` and `END` surrounding the proc body is optional and superfluous.

Comment: @KwaranUngaranBarat . . . You can provide a default value if none is supplied when called.

Comment: can not, because i need data when called